# javascript function inside function not working

Tags: javascript, function, input, timer

i have a timer script that i would like the user to be able to set the amount of time. it works when loading the script when the page loads and setting the timer to a default value, however when i create an input variable and a button to call the function it doesnt work. the "outside" function works however the code that i copy and paste from the working version into the function doesnt. it seems that the inside timer function is never called even though 'var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);' is at the end of the outside function. ive been working on fixing it for hours, and i would like for a more experienced set of eyes to check it out. heres the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function startTimer() {
    var seconds = parseInt(document.getElementById("time").value);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = seconds;
    function secondPassed() {
        document.write(Date());
        var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
        var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
        if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
            remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
        }
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" +    remainingSeconds;
        if (seconds == 0) {
            clearInterval(countdownTimer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz";
        } else {    
            seconds--;
        }
    }
    var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
}
</script>
    <input id="time" type="number">
    <input type="button" value="Set Timer" onClick="startTimer()">
    <span id="countdown" class="timer">Timer: </span>
</body>
```

the "Timer: " text is replaced by the value of the seconds variable but only because of the line before the inside function is defined. the Date() is not printed on the instide function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a *string* to `setTimeout`, so it gets `eval`uated and scope is broken. Only pass functions to `setTimeout`.

```
    var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
```

Comment: That worked! Just curious tho why the string way that i used in the timer set on page load with a default value worked but it didnt work inside of a function?

Comment: Presumably in the working example you haven't shared, `secondPassed` is a global so it is in scope when the string is evaluated.

Comment: If by global you mean not inside another function than yes. Thanks for your help!